# Will Service Reference from Sandbox WSDL work on Production endpoint given there are some differences between the two environments?

Tags: salesforce

Let's say I have both the Production and Sandbox environments.

There are differences between the two - let's just say Sandbox has more modules installed, or the other way around.

I then generate a WSDL from Sandbox, add the Service Reference based on that WSDL and proceed to code up my application in .NET. The .NET application however uses only the methods which would be common to both Sandbox and Production environments, such as login(), query(), using the standard objects such as Lead etc.

Can I simply change the endpoint to point to Production and expect what I coded to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the methods you are calling has same signature in both environment, nothing will cause the problem. If you alter the signature of the methods in service contract, that will cause runtime exception.

Also I would like to comment, if you change (ONLY addition of new members) the data contracts for these Service Methods, it will also work fine. For this to work, your service needs allow ExtensionDataObject. Any extra data from client will be stored in this object on the server.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: So to pose the question again in a different form - as long as I don't use methods with differing signatures in both environment (which do exist in my Service Reference as the WSDL is from Sandbox, and I'm connecting to Production, and both do have differences), then I'm still good?

Comment: If you are not calling the methods with differing signature, nothing will go bad. eg void Foo() is your production method, and void Foo(bool isNew) is your staging method, in this scenario you can not make call to this method in Production with a client created from Sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, if you're only dealing with the standard API calls then yes, changing the end point should be enough. Of course you need to make sure you use the appropriate credentials and security token too!

When you create extra webservices via apex, they have their own WSDL to describe them — if you're using one of those then it should be the same for both environments if the methods are the same. As for custom objects etc., they're supported by the standard WSDLs.

For the sake of completeness, the Partner.wsdl is designed for connecting to different orgs rather than a specific one, so it is identical across environments and it's loosely typed, this may be the best one for your purposes.

> A loosely typed WSDL for customers, partners, and ISVs who are building client applications for multiple organizations. It can be used to access data within any organization.